# YUM not respecing my installation group

Tags: linux, rpm, yum

I've created a custom local repository. I'm attempting to install several hundred custom RPMs by using a `yum` group, but a cursory attempt has failed. `yum` is not recognizing my group. I've tried `yum grouplist | grep mygroup` but it comes up empty.

I've made an rpm, and defined it's group as follows in `groups.xml`:

```
   <!DOCTYPE comps PUBLIC "-//Red Hat, Inc.//DTD Comps info//EN" "comps.dtd">
    <comps>
      <group>
       <id>mygroup</id>
       <default>False</default>
       <uservisible>True</uservisible>
       <display_order>1024</display_order>
       <name>mygroup</name>
       <description></description>
        <packagelist>
          <packagereq type="mandatory">rpm1</packagereq>
                 ...
          <packagereq type="mandatory">rpmN</packagereq>
        </packagelist>
      </group>
    </comps>
```

I create the repo in the correct directory using `createrepo -g groups.xml .`

Then I made the repo file in `/etc/yum.repos.d` which pointed to this location.

```
[JARSS]
name = This is the thing
baseurl = file:///this/is/the/path
```

I know this worked because commands like `yum install rpmN` work, but `yum groupinstall mygroup` do not.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run the `createrepo -g` command you need to specify the path as well. Such as `createrepo -g groups.xml /this/is/the/path`, you should also be placing the groups.xml file in the `/this/is/the/path/` directory (with all the RPMs). I figure you're doing the second part from your question, but I'm not sure about the first part. If you've done that, and you still aren't seeing the group running `yum grouplist`, have you run a `yum clean all` to ensure the data is refreshed?

Comment: If you look closely there is a `.` after the `createrepo` call but it is hard to see. I will try `yum clean all` and report back. Thanks!

Comment: Needed to `yum clean all`, that was it.